# PC can't see a server by name but it can by IP

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns, windows-server-2008-r2

Looked at other similar questions but didn't find a solution.

I have a Win10 Pro tablet on a domain. It can connect to some servers but not others. The same user on a different PC can connect to all servers.

ON THE PROBLEM PC: Windows Explorer can connect via IP, but not by name. Ping by name does not work, ping by IP does work but the name is not returned. .Net ConnectString by name fails also.

I did a ipconfig /flushdns.  Also remove the table from the domain and rejoined.

This doesn't seem to be a NTFS/Share issue, the problem is resolving just some names on this one PC. I can resolve to some servers by name. Other PCs/user have no problem with the server. Nor does this user if logged in on another PC.

nslookup returns server name when IP supplied, but nslookup  can't find the server (on this PC only.)

Any ideas where the problem may be? Next steps to resolve?

Comment: You DNS is messed up, either on your computer, or at the DNS server. since you are on a domain, the DNS server(s) used by the client should be the/a Domain Controller for the domain.  Since you're on a domain, please test other computers and see if they have the same resolution problems, that will help narrow down where the problem exists. As-is this question is too broad, please add details to narrow it.

Comment: Other computers work fine. Same login user on another PC works fine. Other domain users on the same problem PC also fail.

Comment: Too broad - not sure what else I can supply that is not in OP. Problem is with a specific 2008  Win Server and this one Win 10 tablet. All other PCs on the LAN can see the server, just this one device can't resolve the name. I can navigate to \\<ipAddress> just not \\<serverName> from one PC.